# Refazer autoincrement no SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, auto-incremento

Estou passando os dados de um banco antigo para um banco novo. Após executar todas as *querys* existiu alguns campos da chave primaria que ficaram "faltando". Exemplo a coluna `id` pulava do dado '11' para o '13' pois o dado '12' foi apagado. Isso ocorre em diversos casos no banco. Como fazer para apagar completamente os `IDs` e refazê-los para seguir uma ordem correta?

Comment: Não há referências na base de dados a esses IDs? ou seja, sendo que cada ID está associado a uma entrada/linha da tabela, mudar os ID pode fazer com que outras tabelas deixem de funcionar por perderem a referência. Melhor que apagar é fazer um _soft-delete_, que no fundo é uma flag, um dos campos onde se guarda o estado de apagado ou ativo.

Comment: É apenas uma unica tabela sem chave estrangeira, arrumar os IDs me ajudaria a fazer o sort dos dados no futuro. Desconheço o soft-delete, mas acho que ajuda no meu problema. Obg

Comment: Como está a estrutura da tabela? Como foi copiado os dados originais para a tabela? Você não terás os problemas relatados pelo Sergio? O que está querendo não deve ajudar com *sort* algum, e se ajudar tenho medo do que está fazendo.

Comment: A estrura antes estava intacta, com autoincremento correto, porem com rows sem dados, eu as exclui. A estrutura da tabela é esta ![tabela](http://imgur.com/BKNvyHb), em suma a ausência do ID atrapalharia na busca da palavra atraves do sort que fiz em python.

Comment: Em princípio remover o pulo nos IDs me parece contraproducente. Não se ganha nada com isso, e se perde a relação com o DB antigo se no futuro precisar de alguma conferência. Claro que é só você que sabe realmente sua motivação, mas pra mim deu impressão de coisa motivada por "superstição", e isso não combina com programação. Obviamente que é só uma impressão, talvez haja alguma razão legítima que você não tenha mencionado.

Comment: Você não mostrou a estrutura da tabela e sim os dados contidos nela. Talvez não saiba a diferença entre eles. O que me preocupa ainda mais se deve refazer a numeração. Isto tem implicações que eu tenho a impressão que desconheça.

Comment: O motivo real para querer tudo ordenado é literalmente o uma uma função random ira dar um numero e atraves desse numero fazer a busca, queria evitar fazer varias buscas ao banco, se caso o numero buscado tivesse uma row vazia.

Comment: Como estou com os scripts de criação desse novo banco os dados apagado poderam ser desfeitos.

Comment: Re-executei os scripts de geração do banco , retirando os deletes. Fica +/- assim: [tabela](http://imgur.com/24bDA0a) Então a melhor solução seria fazer uma nova busca se caso o dado buscado foi ''?

Comment: Leonardo, se vc fizer o random corretamente, não vai usar os IDs pra nada. Ordene por random e limite pra 1 só, o ID é irrelevante.

Comment: Se a tabela for grande, vc pode usar algo do tipo `LIMIT 1 OFFSET RANDOM() * quantidade_de_registros` pra não indexar a tabela inteira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não ajuda muito mas eu tentaria fazer isto na importação dos dados para a tabela nova:

```
INSERT INTO novatabela (word, definicao, classe_gramatical)
    SELECT word, definicao, classe_gramatical FROM tabelaantiga
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/FromSelect.sql).

Deixe sem o `word_id`, assim a numeração será feita do zero. Garanta que a tabela acabou de ser criada. Se for necessário faça isto em uma tabela temporária, apague a antiga e renomeie a temporária para substituir a antiga.

Fique atento aos comentários na pergunta porque mudar uma chave primária pode ter consequências desastrosas para o banco de dados.

Depender que não tenha buracos nos `ids` não costuma ser uma boa ideia. Você terá que garantir isto, o que não e fácil. Novamente tem comentários dando solução melhor.

[Idealmente não se deve usar `AUTOINCREMENT` para qualquer coisa no SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: Diversas vezes eu li essa página linkada, e a cada vez que eu leio, encontro outra coisa que havia escapado da leitura anterior. Sumário, item 1: `AUTOINCREMENT` normalmente não é necessário; item 2: coluna `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` é um alias para `ROWIDP ; item 3: no `INSERT`, se não for fornecido `ROWID` ou `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, o valor será inferido automaticamente com algum inteiro não utilizado. O único motivo que justifica usar `AUTOINCREMENT` segundo o SQLite é o item 4: o propósito do `AUTOINCREMENT` é evitar o reuso de `ROWID`s antigos já deletados

Comment: É a história da doc do SQLite, tem "tudo" lá, mas tem que prestar muita atenção.